# \autoref does not expand abbreviation automatically at beginning of line

Tags: hyperref

Say there is an equation:

```
\begin{equation}
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \text{.} \label{eq:circ}
\end{equation}
```

I can change the `autoref` label by using:

```
\def\equationautorefname{Eq.}
```

Now, using

```
\autoref{eq:circ} something something \autoref{eq:circ}.
```

gives `Eq. 1 something something Eq. 1.`

However, I want the abbreviated versions to expand if they are at the beginning of a line. Essentially, I want this result here: `Equation 1 something something Eq. 1.` (all hyperlinked of-course). How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately `\autoref` can not distinguish whether you are at the beginning of a line or not...

But we can define an uppercase command `\Autoref` that does the trick (simulating what `\cref` and `\Cref` do with the `cleveref` package):

```
\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand\equationautorefname{Equation}%
  \autoref{#1}%
  \endgroup%
  }
```

Notice that I've encased the definition in `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` so to define it only locally.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\equationautorefname{Eq.}

\newcommand{\Autoref}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand\equationautorefname{Equation}%
  \autoref{#1}%
  \endgroup%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \text{.} \label{eq:circ}
\end{equation}

\Autoref{eq:circ} something something \autoref{eq:circ}.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The basic problem is the detection of the beginning of a sentence (I think, you meant sentence instead of line?). The following heuristics can be used:

- Vertical mode, that means `\autoref` would start a new paragraph.
- `\spacefactor`: The space factor is greater than thousand, if TeX thinks the preceding character ends a sentence.

The previous heuristics is implemented in `\myautoref` in the following example.
`\fullautoref` and `\autoref` allows to specify the full and abbreviated version manually, if the heuristics might fail:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifautorefabbr
\autorefabbrtrue

\renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{%
  \ifautorefabbr
    Eq.\@%
  \else   
    Equation%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\fullautoref}{%
  \@ifstar{\@fullautoref{*}}{\@fullautoref{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@fullautoref}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \autorefabbrfalse
    \autoref#1{#2}%  
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\myautoref}{%
  \@ifstar{\@myautoref{*}}{\@myautoref{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@myautoref}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \ifvmode % \myautoref starts a new paragraph
      \autorefabbrfalse
    \else
      \ifnum\spacefactor>1000 %
        \autorefabbrfalse
      \fi
    \fi  
    \autoref#1{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \text{.} \label{eq:circ}
  \end{equation}   

  \fullautoref{eq:circ} something something \autoref{eq:circ}.
  \fullautoref{eq:circ} something.

  \myautoref{eq:circ} something something \autoref{eq:circ}.
  \myautoref{eq:circ} something.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The star form creates a reference without link.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use the cross-referencing commands of the `cleveref` package. That package's main cross-referencing command is called `\cref`; by default, the variant command `\Cref` both changes the first letter of the object to Uppercase *and* avoids using an abbreviation. (These default settings can be fully customized.)

As you'll see below, `\cref` and `\Cref` automatically insert parentheses around cross-referenced equation numbers. This is very much like the `\eqref` command of the `amsmath` package. If you don't like this setting, it too can be modified.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\def\equationautorefname{Eq.}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % 'nameinlink' used to mimic \autoref's behavior of
                                  % including the cross-reference's name in the link
\setlength\textwidth{4in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \text{.} \label{eq:circ}
\end{equation}
\autoref{eq:circ} something something \autoref{eq:circ}. (\verb+\autoref+)

\noindent
\Cref{eq:circ} something something \cref{eq:circ}. 
(\verb+\Cref+ and \verb+\cref+)
\end{document}
```